# nvidia nforce 10/100 mbps ethernet driver and Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, drivers, network-adapter

I have a compaq presario here on which I have stupidly installed Windows XP before doing any research. Now I don't have a single driver for any device on the computer. Luckily, I've found a driver for the video card, but I can't find the driver for the network adapter.

According to the device manager, the adapter is "nvidia nforce 10/100 mbps ethernet." I am having no luck finding a driver for this, or even any suggestion that the thing even exists outside of this PC in my office.

Any ideas on how to get the driver for this thing? Or some other method for getting it connected to the internet?

Comment: What is the presario model number specifically?

Comment: its a CQ5320Y. All the drivers on compaq's site for this model are for vista or 7 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.nvidia.com/object/nforce_winxp_15.45.html  This will most likely run on your Compaq, provided it is less than 3 years old. If you are not sure, then on nVidia's page, in the dropdown boxes where you chose which driver to install, there is an nForce option.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Computer is running fine now.